# Access making text box on forms static

Tags: ms-access, vba

I currently have a form in access which has text boxes which refreshes itself every time you click on it. I am assuming that access has a dynamic way of updating the tables, ie as soon as you move the cursor away from the text box, it updates the tables. Is there any way of making this static ie. I should have a button which after clicking updates a set of text boxes into the table. Although this is not a feature which is desired, I am planning to use this to prevent multiple users corrupting the data in the table.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you're asking for is standard behavior... The record will not be saved until the record has lost focus, rather than the field. If your form is saving after each field loses focus (desired in some applications) it has been set up that way (probably with an `OnChanged` event on the textbox).